# Crystal Report não permite criar parâmetro

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

Estou tentanto criar um parametro no Crystal Report e quando clico no Ok nada acontece.
Existe limitação de parametros no crystal em um projeto? pois li algo parecido em outro forum.
Seria alguma configuração? o que eu fiz foi:
Botão direito em cina do "Campos de Parâmetro" - "Novo" e abriu essa janela abaixo. Mudei o nome e nada acontece no clique do OK.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não aparece no "Explorador de Campos" ? Tenho CR com uma dezena de parâmetros ...

Comment: tenta atribuir algum valor "fixo" em opções de valor para o parâmetro ou tente apenas mudando o tipo, não vi ainda casos de limite de parâmetros no CR

Answer (score 0):

Passe um valor para o parâmetro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz um exemplo com tipo numérico segue abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]